# securing login php script

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a login system where the inserted_id and inserted_password are sent to the `login.inc.php` via the `XMLHttpRequest`. I'm not sure if my php script is secure. I need some securing advice for my script.

..............................................................................

`login.inc.php:`

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "users");
    $params = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    $inserted_id = $params['inserted_id'];
    $inserted_password = $params['inserted_password'];

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE account_name=? OR email=?;")) {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $inserted_id, $inserted_id);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt));
        if ($row == null) {
            echo ("DOESNT EXISTS");
        } else {
            if (password_verify($inserted_password, $row['password'])) {
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
                echo("SUCCESS");
            } else {
                echo("PASSWORD_FAIL");
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

`signup.inc.php:`

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "users");
    $params = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    $inserted_first_name = $params['first_name'];
    $inserted_last_name = $params['last_name'];
    $inserted_dob = $params['dob'];
    $inserted_email = $params['email'];
    $inserted_account_name = $params['account_name'];
    $inserted_password = $params['password'];

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email=?;")) {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $inserted_email);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        if (mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt)) > 0) {
            echo("EMAIL_TAKEN");
        } else {
            $hashed_password = password_hash($inserted_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            $created_id = rand(111111111, 999999999);
            $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
            if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, "INSERT INTO user(id, first_name, last_name, dob, email, account_name, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);")) {
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "issssss", $created_id, $inserted_first_name, $inserted_last_name, $inserted_dob, $inserted_email, $inserted_account_name, $hashed_password);
                $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                echo ($result ? "SUCCESS" : "FAIL");
            }
        }
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
?>
```

Comment: I don't understand this bit: `echo ("EXISTS");`, what's that for?

Comment: Was meant to echo DOESN'T EXISTS. to check if user_id exisits

Comment: Unless your implementing authentication as a learning exercise, I would recommend not reinventing the wheel here. If you're really concerned about security, use a purpose built solution like Firebase or one of the numerous auth libraries for php.

Comment: @Aman: While cegfault has made a reasonable attempt at answering this, it is a little off topic here - codereview.stackexchange.com might be a more appropriate place to ask this question. Please bear in mind that you have invited comments from people in a public forum, and you should be critical of the responses (some of which are not very helpful)

Comment: @symcbean I will ask on codereview. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security is an entire field of study, and there's no easy way to measure whether or not something is "secure" or not secure.  Security often involves not only code, but software releases, organizational changes, etc.

Here are the first things I noticed right off the bat in your posted code:

- Using `$_GET` to pull in a password means the password was not POST'd, and therefore may exist in logs (client, server, and even some ISPs)
- your `mysqli_connect` call is using `root` as a username.  Don't use `root` in production code.  Make an other user.
- your `root` mysql user .... *has no password?!?!?!*
- Using `SELECT * FROM` may return more rows than anticipated, especially because you have no `LIMIT` argument.  Depending on database size, and how things get entered into the database, this could be abused.
- `WHERE account_name=? OR email=?` - what if I make an account name that's someone else's email?  Or enter the account name of another user in my "email" field?  Your code might give me access to their profile (or lock me out of mine)
- The code is not wrapped in a function, which means someone who can edit other PHP files (such as extensions) - which might be included'd after this php file - might be able to see the `$inserted_password` variable, which reveals the password!

Comment: Almost right. Password_verify() is a built-in function - http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php and the point about not wrapping it in a function is spurious

Comment: @symcbean good catch. removed those two notes.  I thought for some reason `password_verify()` was his own function.  I was wrong; forgot it was a built-in library function.  I personally wouldn't rely on it for password storage, but that might be more preference

Comment: @cegfault 
1. I have changed my code in the question for `$_GET` area
2. I will change that later
3. For test use I haven't assigned password
4. I will change that later
5. I DONT UNDERSTAND
6. I DONT UNDERSTAND